# Android: including ndk .so libraries for different architectures, app crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, libraries

I'm not new to Android development but I'm a total newbie when speaking about NDK and .so libraries.

The app I'm building uses third party SDKs and they provide some .so files. They provide me with an .so file for every architecture (so far: arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, mips64, x86, x86_64).

I need to include a new third party SDK but they only provide .so files for armeabi-v7a and x86.
When I try to run my app, it crashes and I get an error from the SDK (I see it on logcat) that states:

> **SDKNAME** currently only provides prebuilt library for **armeabi-v7a** and **x86** architectures

Is this a common scenario ? is there a way to fix this kind of scenario ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: By my understanding, you could only build your project for armeabi-v7a or x86 architectures. Please check which build variant you are using, it is highly likely no to be any of those.

Comment: I'm not using anything specifying architectures on my build configs. Again, I'm a super n00b. 
I found this:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html

Do you think it can help ?

Comment: You should provide more information, for example: using Android Studio or Eclipse, configuration files ...

Comment: I'm using Android Studio (2.2.3), the config file has nothing special. I tried on a blank project and the same happens (when I include those two SDKs)

Comment: If your device is arm64, you should remove all 64 bit libraries from your APK until you get 64 bit versions for all of them. If the device has MIPS CPU, you are out of luck with your new dependencies because ARM simulation is not good enough. Finally, there may be toolchain incompatibilities between the 3rd party libraries even on the "conventional" arm-v7a platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your compiled libraries in app/src/main/jniLibs/{arch} for example: armeabi/armeabi-v7a and then add the lines at the end of the post to your apps build.gradle.

The productFlavours is used to configure the compilation variants, so this way you could link properly already compiled libraries.

```
android.ndk {
        moduleName = "your_library_jni"
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-I" + file("src/main/jni").absolutePath)
        }

android.productFlavors {
        create("x86") {
            ndk.with{
                abiFilters.add("armeabi")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libyour_module.so")

            }
        }
        create("arm-v7a") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")

                File curDir = file('./')
                curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/"

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libyour_module.so")

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have all libraries available for all architectures that your application will support.

When the APK is installed, the installer scans the APK for what architectures it supports. If an APK doesn't include native code, it supports all architectures. If it does include native code however, it only supports those architectures that are included in the APK. Most modern devices support more than one architecture; for example, a device might support `arm64-v8a` and `armeabi-v7a`, or `x86_64` and `x86`, or `x86` and `armeabi-v7a` (via emulation). On installation, it looks through which architectures are included, picks the most preferred architecture of those, and installs all libraries from that architecture, ignoring the rest. (Older Android versions may unintentionally have shown a slightly different, inconsistent behaviour in cases like the one described - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648943/3115956.)

Now if one of the libraries you include comes in builds for all available architectures, while another one only supports a few, the installer might pick e.g. `arm64-v8a`, and thus not get all the necessary libraries.

Thus, you can only support the intersection of architectures provided by all of your libraries.

To achieve this, you can either manually remove the excess directories from the SDKs that provide more architectures, or if using Gradle to build your APK, you can add this to a NDK block:

```
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
```